# TypeScript compile modules with wrong path

Tags: typescript

I have React component in /Scripts/ShiftPlan/test.tsx and it looks like this:

```
import React = require('react');

const test: React.StatelessComponent<React.HTMLProps<JSX.Element>> = () =>
    <div>
        Test component
    </div>

export = () => React.createElement(test, {})
```

and my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "outFile": "site.js",
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "amd",
    "typeRoots": [ "../node_modules/@types/**/" ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot",
    "typings",
    "Tests"
  ],
  "include": [ "./**/*.tsx", "./**/*.ts" ]
}
```

problem is that my test component will compile into site.js like this:

```
define("test", ["require", "exports", "react"], function (require, exports, React) {
    "use strict";
    var test = function () {
        return React.createElement("div", null, "sadsad");
    };
    return function () { return React.createElement(test, {}); };
});
```

but it shloud be

```
define("ShiftPlan/test"....
```

Thanks so much for any advice.